# How to call servlet when loading jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am very new to servlets. I have a jsp page that calls a servlet which is executed on a submit button within a form.

It works, returning the data to the page. However I would like my servlet to be executed on load of the jsp.

Comment: Mihir I tried that steps but didn't get any luck.

Comment: Kayaman I tried that steps but didn't get any luck.

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? What is your code. By "on load" you mean servlet should execute continuously till the jsp page is running?

Comment: @GauravMahindra As in asp.net with c#, if we want to execute any method only once from a class at the time of page load, then we call that method on page load. So I actually want to do the same using servlet/jsp and it should call only once not continuously.

Comment: In your application, why you want to perform this I mean what task you want to accomplish by doing this. Until it is unknown, difficult to help you.